# What encoding type of these text?

Tags: character-encoding

When I search in Google by Thai language. Google will convert like these.
%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A9%E0%B8%B2%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Encoding: See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

> It's a URL encoding in which all
>   non-alphanumeric characters except
>   `-_.` are replaced with a percent (%)
>   sign followed by two hex digits and
>   spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It
>   is encoded the same way that the
>   posted data from a WWW form is
>   encoded, that is the same way as in
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   media type.

(Information copied from http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 + URL Encoding.