# Cyrillic characters in browser address bar

Tags: browser, address-bar

When I put cyrillic symbols in address bar like this:

[https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=привет](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)

it switches to

https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=%EF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2

What does that characters -- %EF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2 -- mean? And why is it happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428443/what-encoding-type-of-these-text

Answer (score 5):

The characters are getting [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). A URL may only contain a subset of ASCII characters, so anything outside plain alphanumeric and some special characters must be URL encoded.

Some browsers display non-ASCII characters as human readable characters, but that's entirely up to them. In protocols, URLs are always URL encoded.

Comment: cite from php.net:

Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs.

But what do those "two hex digits" mean?

Comment: @Zapadlo: Thank you very much for posting a snippet from the documentation of a more or less random language.

Comment: Thank you for reading my comment so carefully. Try once more, from the beginning.

[Hint: cite from php.net. php.net. php.] Congrats, you got it.