# Make Cyrillic characters appear as they are(without encoding) in browser address bar

Tags: url, browser, encoding, decoding, address-bar

Basically, when I put Cyrillic symbols in address bar like this:

```
https://venta.uz/items/men/#?categories=мужское
```

it gets encoded and appears in URL address bar like this:

```
https://venta.uz/items/men/#?categories=%5B%22%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%22%5D
```

Similar questions have been asked a couple of times, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483613/cyrillic-characters-in-browser-address-bar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483613/cyrillic-characters-in-browser-address-bar) for example. But they all asked why this happens.

Here is why it happens:

> It's a URL encoding in which all
>   non-alphanumeric characters except
>   `-_.` are replaced with a percent (%)
>   sign followed by two hex digits and
>   spaces encoded as plus (+) signs.

My question is:

Is it possible to fix this? maybe there is a workaround or hack that would allow Cyrillic characters appear as they are in the URL address bar?

Comment: A fix assumes something is broken and it's not the case here. By the way, FireFox keeps Cyrillic characters as they are without encoding (possibly because I have Russian as system-wide language for non-Unicode programs, but maybe it is unrelated).

Comment: @RomanR. you are right. Firefox keeps those characters as they are. But the reason you mentioned is, I think, unrelated. Because, I have Russian in my Chrome too :(

Comment: My FF & Chrome keep russian letters in URL (Windows 8, non-russian regional settings)
http://screencast.com/t/gpE4RNnNr

Comment: @AleksejVasinov, I just noticed that if I put Cyrillic characters in a query string(as GET parameters) they are being rendered as they are. But if I put such characters in hash part, they are being encoded, like [here](https://venta.uz/items/men/#?subCats=%5B%22%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%22%5D)

Comment: This strikes me as a very malicious question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour to convert urls to some kind of a machinery text is a technique against fishing attacks, when attacker register domains like "googlе.com", "аpplе.com" with substituded similar-looking unicode characters ("a" and "e" in this examples are cyrillic).

This is kind of annoying for any non-english speakers of course, because copied URSs become enormous and unreadable.

For Firefox the solution is quite simple (thanks to this answer from [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/480692/copying-unicode-symbols-from-firefox-address-bar-as-is)): go to `about:config` and set `browser.urlbar.decodeURLsOnCopy` to **true**.

For Chrome and it's derivatives you won't find this kind of setting.
Instead you can use extensios like [Copy Unicode URLs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-unicode-urls/fnbbfiapefhkicjhecnoepbijhanpkjp).