# Vaadin setUriFragment UTF-8 character

Tags: utf-8, vaadin

```
getPage().setUriFragment("абв-руский");
```

result in browser:

```
%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9
```

how to show that in browser correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can't show that in browser correctly,

According to [Cyrillic characters in browser address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483613/cyrillic-characters-in-browser-address-bar) some browsers will show it correctly, it fully depends on the character set it is using.

Comment: for getPage().setLocation("абв-руский") I have no poblem. Because i think it's possible

Comment: Yes it is possible. The problem here is that you can not write cyrillic characters into the address bar without seeing URL encoded chars. Read the topic I linked and you'll easily see why.

Answer (score 0):

temporary solution was

```
String urlBase = "http://yourdomain.tld/"; 
String url = "абв-руский";
Page.getCurrent().open(urlBase + url, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved in Vaadin 8.